# How do I get regex to only print the first of an array of information found?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, web-scraping

So I'm new to web scraping and I've been stuck on this problem for awhile now.

I'm using Python w/ Regex to try and get a certain value of a class and while I do get the information I want, I get it in an array followed by a bunch of other junk I don't want. How do I get regex to only give me the first of the array?

The line of code looks like this:

```
'<td class="item_dropped">(.+?)</td>'
```

And to visualize the above statement the data that comes out looks like this:

```
['1,453,343,231 ABC', '24,131,411 TPP', '<a href="/item/13445/">Foo</a>', '<a href="/item/3453/">Bar</a>']
```

and I am trying to only grab "`1,453,343,231 ABC`" out of that. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Do not try to parse a non regular language (HTML) with regular expressions. You will have a bad time.

Comment: Hum... So you want to access the first item of your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if your list variable is called `result`, you can do:

```
>>> print result[0]
1,453,343,231 ABC
```

The `list_name[index]` syntax fetches the element of the list at the number index (indexing starts at 0). Therefore, the index of 0 will fetch the 1st element.

Comment: Wow, that was simpler than I expected. I feel a bit silly now, but you solved my problem, thank you. :)

Comment: Of course, I always upvote answers and select best answers. You solved exactly what I asked, I don't see why I wouldn't.^^